# how to print arduino accelerometer real time data to file

Tags: python

The program below compiles but doesn't print data to file. I also tried while(1) but didn't get the right output (no data).  I am still trying to learn python embedded and file programming. Can anybody take a look and point me in the right direction?

Code below:

```
  import logging
  import serial
  import serial.threaded
  import threading
  #import time
  #from datetime import *
  #import datetime
  import time as t
  from datetime import datetime

  import sys




    ser = serial.Serial('COM3',baudrate=9600, timeout=1)

    def getvalues():
      arduionoData=ser.readline().decode('ascii') #('UTF-8')#
      return arduionoData

    def realtime():
        """Generate time string"""
        dt0 = datetime.now()
        dt1 = dt0.replace(minute=1*(int)(dt0.minute),second=
              (int)(dt0.second),microsecond=0)
        return dt1.time().strftime('%H:%M:%S')




        extraction_file = open("C:/Users/gurbir/Desktop/Arduino   /accelerometerXonly_jul09a/extraction.txt",     "w")

      #while(1):  


       extraction_file.write(getvalues())
       #extraction_file.write(realtime())
       t.sleep(3) #try to collect data for 3 seconds
       extraction_file.close()
       sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

try to write csv file

```
import csv
while(1):
      with open(r'log.csv', 'a') as f:
           writer = csv.writer(f)
           writer.writerow((getvalues()))
```

Comment: It worked, however, is there a graceful way to exit out of the while loop after 3 seconds?